# Why are all the lines of my input file being read into the first element of my array instead of separate elements?

Tags: arrays, windows, perl

I'm trying to store each line of a text file as an element in an array. My text file looks like this:

```
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
Element 4
Element 5
Element 6
Element 7
Element 8
```

I tried this code:

```
$FilePath = "File/Path/Elements.txt";
open my $handle, '<', $FilePath;
chomp(my @array = <$handle>);
close $handle;
print "$array[0]\n\n$array[2]";
```

but I got this output:

```
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
Element 4
Element 5
Element 6
Element 7
Element 8
```

even though I expect this output:

```
Element 1

Element 3
```

All the lines are stored in the first element `$array[0]` and nothing is stored in the other elements including element `$array[2]`.

I also tried the following, but got the same output:

```
$FilePath = "File/Path/Elements.txt";
my @array;
open(my $handle, "<", $FilePath)
while(<$handle>) { 
    chomp; 
    push @array, $_;
} 
close $handle;
print "$array[0]\n\n$array[2]";
```

How can I get my expected output? I'm using Perl on Windows.

Comment: What kind of line endings does the input file have?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $array[0]` to see what you are getting from the file.  Also check if $/ has been changed

Comment: What is the origin of `Elements.txt`? Has it come from an Apple system perhaps? Or alternatively, does your code alter the built-in variable `$/`? Does it make any difference if you temporarily add `local $/ = "\n";` before the `while` loop? And please show the result of ysth's diagnostic code

Comment: @mob The line endings of the file is `\n` generated via Perl Windows.

Comment: @ysth The result is:
    
`Element 1
    Element 2
    Element 3
    Element 4
    Element 5
    Element 6
    Element 7
    Element 8
    $VAR1 = "Element 1\nElement 2\nElement 3\nElement 4\nElement 5\nElement 6\nElement 7\nElement 8";`

Comment: @Borodin The origin of the file is Windows system. It's generated via perl code using `\n` as the new line delimiter.
When I've added `local $/ = "\n";` before `while` loop, the result was as expected correctly. ysth's diagnostic code showed that the newline delimiter used is `\n`

Comment: it may actually be \r\n and reading it is converting it.  but since setting $/ fixes it, clearly somewhere you are leaving $/ set badly.  (\n is its default)

Comment: @ysth Could using `undef $/;` with other previous `open()` forces us to redefine `$/` again?

Comment: @omareg: Absolutely. Apart from affecting how files are read, it's just an ordinary variable. Nothing will change its value apart from an explicit assignment that you have written. If you want to alter it temporarily, for instance to read an entire file at once, you should enclose the file reading in a block (between braces `{ ... }`) that starts with `local $/`. That will automatically restore the original value outside the block

Comment: @Borodin The code is now running correctly without using `local $/ = "\n";` when I used `{... local $/; undef $/; ... }` for all `open ()` that has the `undef $/;`. The problem was definitely caused by the not localized `undef $/`. Thanks a lot for all your help!! @Borodin @ysth

Comment: @omareg94: I'm pleased you have it working. There's no need to `undef $/` -- just `local $/` will set it to undefined

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks a lot, it really worked fine. Could you please write an answer to make the question marked as answered?